# custom sort of `by=`

Tags: r, data.table

When I do manipulations with tables using `by=`, the resulting table have the same order of records as in original table:

```
dt1 <- fread(
  "colA,colB
   B,3
   A,1
   C,2
   B,1
   C,2
  ")

 desired <- c('A', 'C', 'B')    

#> dt1[, mean(colB), by=colA]
#   colA V1
#1:    B  2
#2:    A  1
#3:    C  2
```

But what if I need to have it in not in this original order (`B A C` here) and not in usual `sort()` order (which would be `A B C` or `C B A`), but in my custom order (say, `A C B`)? Should I somehow use `rank` with the resulting table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could re-`order` after the aggregation is done

```
dt1[, mean(colB), by=colA][order(desired),]
#    colA V1
# 1:    A  1
# 2:    C  2
# 3:    B  2
```

Thanks to Arun for clearing up the issue.  You have erroneous spaces in your table.  Remove them, and then you can use `order` (above), or the join suggestion by Arun (below).

```
dt1[, colA := gsub(" ", "", colA)]
dt1[, mean(colB), keyby=colA][desired]
#    colA V1
# 1:    A  1
# 2:    C  2
# 3:    B  2
```

Have a look at the original data:

```
dt1 <- fread(
  "colA,colB
   B,3
   A,1
   C,2
   B,1
   C,2
  ")
dput(dt1)
# structure(list(colA = c("   B", "   A", "   C", "   B", "   C"  ...
#        extra space ----- ^^^
```

Comment: Alternatively you could join as follows: `dt1[, mean(colB), keyby=colA][.(desired)]`. or simply `dt1[, mean(colB), keyby=colA][desired]` (because it's a single character column).

Comment: @Arun - When I run that and get a column of `NA` in `V1`

Comment: That's because of spaces in his `dt1$colA`. Do `dt1[, colA := gsub(" ", "", colA)]` and then try again.

Comment: Thank you all for explanation, sorry for erroneous sample data